# How to debug high memory consumption

Tags: c++, debugging, opencv, memory

I wrote a program which use OpenCV persistence module to read a .xml.gz file. I use a class to manage these data. In the constructor, it use `cv::FileStorage` read all the data. All data are in member variables which are either `std::vector` or `cv::Mat`. There are no static members or anything shared between each instance of the class.

Here is the strange thing. If I use only one instance of my class, the program will consume about 50MB memory. However, if I use two instances, it will consume about 600MB. If I use three, it will consume about 650MB. If I use four, it will consume about 700MB ... There seems to be a strange line between only one instance and more than one instance.

I did some experiments and here are some results:

1. This problem only happens on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04, OpenCV 3.0), not on Windows.
2. I use valgrind to check, and there is no memory leak in the program.

Here is the code of this class: https://github.com/delphifirst/FaceX/blob/master/FaceX/face_x.cpp

Pointing out the problem in my code or give me some suggestions for debugging this kind of problems will both be very helpful.

Edit:
I follow the suggestions in the comment, and use top -p instead of gnome-system-monitor to check the memory consumption. The result is: 
VIRT: 1003552, RES: 693228, SHR: 8440, %MEM: 33.8 (The computer has 2GB memory in total)

Edit2:
I use tcmalloc to replace g++'s memory allocator, then the problem disappeared mysteriously.

Comment: How are you measuring the memory consumption?

Comment: One suggestion to debug is to write a memory query class that gives you PSS or RES or VIRT memory . You may  use an object of this query class after each block and see where memory increases.

Comment: gnome-system-monitor

Comment: Some times lib in c++ wont release the memory  back to OS due to performance sake.

Comment: @SatishChalasani When I use only one instance, the memory consumption will rise to about 600MB temporarily, but will decrease to 50MB at last. Therefore, I think OpenCV use these memory to parse xml file. But why it return the memory when I use on instance and doesn't when I use more than one~~

Comment: Have you looked if you are copying the same data multiple times when creating instance second time?

Comment: @delphifirst  memory management is not all times obivious. Based on current consumption, memory manager may think you are going to use high water memory. So it will keep it for performance sake. With one instance may be it didn't cross the threshold where it takes the decision to keep or release it.

Comment: I have checked the code many times and couldn't find this kind of problems.

Comment: @delphifirst Please check my earlier comment on crossing the threshold. I ran into this problem and this comment is based on my research.

Comment: If you explained how you are measuring memory use, you might get a better explanation of why that method of measuring is wrong.  A meaningful measure is far more difficult than you would expect.  I am nearly certain the unusual memory consumption you are seeing is an artifact of the inherent inaccuracy in the way you are measuring, rather than an actual performance issue.  VIRT may be wildly and inconsistently higher than any meaningful measure of use.  RES will stay closer to meaningful, but not enough to trust.

Comment: I believe gnome-system-monitor is showing you consumption of virtual memory which isn't a scarce resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can link to tcmalloc (a memory allocation library that will replace the usual memory allocation routines in your program) and use its heap profiler. The heap profiler will tell you where your memory consumption is coming from (i.e. which functions in your program are allocating all that memory). That should give you a good starting point for further debugging.

Comment: Does it work if the memory allocation may happen in third-party library? In my case, the memory may be allocated by OpenCV.

Comment: @delphifirst yes, unless they use their own memory allocator (which is unlikely).

Comment: @Aaronl I followed your suggestion, and use tcmalloc, and then mysterious thing happened: The problem disappeared...